# Blazor: String literal in the event handler code?

Tags: c#, blazor

Let's say that I have added the following to the `WeatherForecastService.cs":

```
    public string Hello(string name)
    {
        return $"Hello, {name}!";
    }
```

How can I pass `"World"` to it? All the examples I could find were calling methods that have no arguments, so they did not help. I have tried the followings:

```
<button @onclick="() => { Message = ForecastService.Hello(world); }">Click</button>
```

-> causes 'undefined' error, of course.

```
<button @onclick="() => { Message = ForecastService.Hello('world'); }">Click</button>
```

-> causes 'too many characters' error.

```
<button @onclick="() => { Message = ForecastService.Hello(\"world\"); }">Click</button>
```

-> causes lots of errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few answers [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10138) for this on the Blazor GitHub site. [This answer](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10138#issuecomment-504667551) worked for me.

Basically, you need to add `@(...)` around your lambda:

```
<button @onclick="@(() => { Message = ForecastService.Hello('world'); })">Click</button>
```